# MiniTest : Should not skip functions on assert fail

Tags: ruby, minitest

Currently, one of my test functions has 8 assertions. If the first one fails, It skips the remaining assertions and goes to the next function. How can this behaviour be changed?

Comment: How would you like it to behave? Please paste the test.

Answer (score 2):

In short: You can not.

I assume you have something like this:

```
def test_foo
  assert_equal 0, Foo.calculate(nil)
  assert_equal 0, Foo.calculate()
  assert_equal 12, Foo.calculate(8, 4)
  assert_equal 0, Foo.calculate(4, -4)
  ...
end
```

A lot of assertions inside a single test method. What you could do is to split this into multiple test methods:

```
def test_result_when_input_is_nil
  assert 0, Foo.calculate(nil)
end

def test_result_when_no_input
  assert 0, Foo.calculate()
end

def test_calculates_result
  assert 12, Foo.calculate(8, 4)
end

def test_can_handle_negative_numbers
  assert 0, Foo.calculate(4, -4)
end
```

You get better error messages from this as it is clear when something breaks and where it broke.